# Safe cancellation of pthreads using a cleanup handler in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

We've been given some code to look at in preparation for an exam regarding pthreads and cancelling them properly. We've been asked to both explain what is wrong, and fix it.

My answer: The thread handler function enters a wait state without releasing the mutex, but I feel like I'm missing something. Here is the code, the lines adding a clean up handler were added to fix the program. Again, I'm not quite sure WHY this works. (I understand the concept of the clean up handler, but I don't understand why it fixes this particular problem - another reason why I'm not sure that my answer is correct)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
const int flag = 1;

static void * cancelme(void *bb_in)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  /* Install a cleanup handler */
  pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, &mutex);

  while (flag) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mutex);
  }

  //before insertion of cleanup handlers: pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); was here

  /* Uninstall cleanup handler */
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1);



  return (NULL);
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t t;
  pthread_create(&t, NULL, cancelme, NULL);
  sleep(1);
  pthread_cancel(t);

  printf("Waiting for thread to finish...\n");
  pthread_join(t, NULL);
  printf("Thread finished...\n");

  printf("Waiting to acquire lock...\n");
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  printf("Lock acquired\n");

  return (0);
}
```

Any feedback much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt this is the bug your instructor is looking for, but `pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, &mutex);` is invalid. The first argument to `pthread_cleanup_push` is of type `void(*)(void*)`, not `int(*)(pthread_mutex_t*)`. You must make a wrapper function of the right type that invokes `pthread_mutex_unlock`, i.e. `static void cleanup(void *p) { pthread_mutex_unlock(p); }`

Comment: Thanks for that, but what he's really looking for is why the program falls over before the pthread_cleanup_push and pthread_cleanup_pop were put into the code, ie after the while loop the line

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
Was in the code (I've commented it out in the pasted version above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the code to push the `pthread_mutex_unlock` function onto the thread's cleanup stack via `pthread_cleanup_push` makes the code snippet work because otherwise the thread would grab the shared lock and be forced to exit without releasing it.

By pushing the `pthread_mutex_unlock` function onto the cleanup stack, the thread is ensuring that the mutex will get unlocked when the thread exits, even if the exit is forced and the `pthread_cleanup_pop` function is not hit.

In essence the cleanup queue gives you the ability to ensure code gets executed / resources are freed / etc upon exit. The `pthread_cleanup_pop function` just calls the top function on the cleanup stack, while exiting calls all the functions on the cleanup stack. See the man of `pthread_cleaup_push` for more info.